# Spring MVC @Transient Angular JAVA DTO Pass the value from backend to frontend

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, dto, transient

I'm using the spring MVC and I want to pass the int **value** calculated in the @Service to front site in angularjs using @transient annotations.

Here's my entity with @transient value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "oferty_pracy")
public class Preference {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_oferta")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_oferta;
    private String tytul_oferty_pracy;
    private String preferowany_jezyk;
    private String wyksztalcenie;
    private String opis_oferta;
    private String nazwa_firmy;
    private String kontakt_firma;
    private String wojewodztwo;
    private Integer id_uzytkownika;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "preference", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<PreferenceRecomendations> preferenceRecomendations;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_uzytkownika", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public User user;

    @Transient
    public Integer value;

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

I'm don't know how can I use this value in the Service, because it's null. I'm using the DTO, here's my controller: the **MatchingValue** is displayed on the front

```
private List<OfferDTO> transformToDTO(List<PreferenceRecomendations> recommendationList) {
        List<OfferDTO> offerList = new ArrayList<OfferDTO>();
        for (PreferenceRecomendations preferenceRecomendations : recommendationList) {
            OfferDTO offerDTO = new OfferDTO();
            offerDTO.setDetails(preferenceRecomendations.getPreference().getOpis_oferta());
            offerDTO.setCompany(preferenceRecomendations.getPreference().getNazwa_firmy());
            offerDTO.setTitle(preferenceRecomendations.getPreference().getTytul_oferty_pracy());
            offerDTO.setContact(preferenceRecomendations.getPreference().getKontakt_firma());
            offerDTO.setMatching_offer(preferenceRecomendations.getPreference().getValue());
            offerList.add(offerDTO);
        }
        return offerList;
```

And I don't know how I must get and send the **value**, because when I want to get this value in the service it's null:

```
@Service
public class DefaultRecomendationsService implements RecomendationsService {

    @Autowired
    public RecommendationsDAO recomDAO;

    public List<PreferenceRecomendations> proposeRecomendations(SearchForm searchForm) {
        List<PreferenceRecomendations> oferty_pracy = recomDAO.lista_rekomendacji_oferty_pracy();
        List<Preference> form_list = recomDAO.form_list();
        List<PreferenceRecomendations> oferta_spelniajaca_preferencje = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> testowa_tablica = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> testowa_tablica_najlepsze_preferencje = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> tablica_zgodnosc_preferencji = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int dopasowanie = recomendation_form.getValue();
float zgodnosc_zgodnosci = liczba_zgodnych_tagow.size();
float zgodnosc_zgodnosci_formularz = liczba_wybranych_tagow_w_formularzu;
float k = (zgodnosc_zgodnosci / zgodnosc_zgodnosci_formularz) * 100;
System.out.println("K: " + k);
dopasowanie = Math.round(k);
```

In the line: 
**int dopasowanie = recomendation_form.getValue();**
I throught I get the value from the entity and then I can operated that's **value** but it's null and I can't do anything.

Please help me, because I don't know how can I fix this :(

Update: the RecomendationsDAO class (I'm using the hibernate criteria):

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RecommendationsDAOimpl implements RecommendationsDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecommendationsDAOimpl.class);

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void save(Recomendation r) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(r);
        logger.info("Recomendation saved successfully, recomendations details=" + r);
    }

    // tagi_umiejetnosci table"umiejetnosci" do rekomendacji
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Recomendation> recomendationsList() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Recomendation.class);
        List<Recomendation> recomendation = criteria.list();

        return recomendation;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Recomendation> the_best_recomendations() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria3 = session.createCriteria(Recomendation.class);
        List<Recomendation> bestie_recomendations = criteria3.list();

        return bestie_recomendations;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<PreferenceRecomendations> lista_rekomendacji_oferty_pracy() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria2 = session.createCriteria(PreferenceRecomendations.class);
        List<PreferenceRecomendations> rekomendacja_ofert_pracy = criteria2.list();

        return rekomendacja_ofert_pracy;
    }

    // tagi_lang_edu table"oferty_pracy" do rekomendacji
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Preference> form_list() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Preference.class);
        List<Preference> form_preference_list = criteria.list();

        return form_preference_list;
    }
```

Comment: How you retrieve the entity? Show your `RecommendationsDAO` class too

Comment: I edited the post and I add this class :)

Comment: cool, but it's seems the reason you got null on `value` was because `@Transient` annotations. this annotations made the value won't persist on the database: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html. Try remove that annotations, and it will fix your `null` error

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to save this int value. It's dynamic element, depends on what the user chooses in the form, and signify the match of user preferences, for example in the service I calculated this value and I get "dopasowanie = 60" and this "60" I want send to the front by dto and "matchingValue"

Comment: I do not know how to use this annotation for what I want to do, maybe I complicate something simple, but I don't use it before.

Comment: On your service, where this `recomendation_form` variable came from? I don't see any initialization for this variable?

Comment: I past the elements related with "recomendation_form":

{List<Preference> form_list = recomDAO.form_list();
Preference recomendation_form = form_list.get(a);}

form_list is the list with user's preferences.